# How resolve marathon leader with mesos-dns

Tags: marathon

I've installed mesos-dns in our cluster and is running ok. We can check the domain of the apps installed in marathon but I would like to know in which host is installed the marathon itself. If I do a dig to marathon.domain is not resolving anything.

According to the doc of mesos-dns: "A records (`{framework}.domain`) and SRV records `(_framework._tcp.{framework}.domain)` - for every known Mesos master"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's `marathon.mesos` unless you've used a different TLD. The Marathon scheduler runs on the Master.

Comment: returns:
;; ANSWER SECTION:
marathon.mesos.         60      IN      A       127.0.0.1


but not the IP of the master.

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about a DC/OS setup. Did you execute the `dig` command on the Master?

Comment: In the master host I have not added the nameserver of the mesos-dns. the mesos-dns nameserver is added only in the slaves (one entry in etc/resolv.conf). According to the doc I think that is not necessary to add in the masters. I am not using DC/OS setup.

Comment: So, anyone that could help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [mesosdns-resolver](https://github.com/tobilg/mesosdns-resolver) bash script to get the endpoint from Mesos DNS.

You can use it like:

```
mesosdns-resolver.sh -sn <service-name>.marathon.mesos -s <IP_ADDRESS_OF_MESOS_DNS_SERVER>
```